# IE10 SCRIPT5: Access is denied. on new FormData

Tags: visual-studio, publish, web-deployment, webdeploy

This works in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox, however in IE10 I get this error:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 $('.mlsUpload').change(function () {
var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
});
```

It happens on the `new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0])`

The change is on a display:none input type=file, which is the only thing in the form.

Comment: It seems IE 10 limits access to the local storage if the site is not among trusted. Can you disable the protected mode and see?

Comment: @Hariprasad I disabled protected mode and am still having the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on *why* but this code seems to have fixed the issue and works on all browsers.

```
var formData = new FormData();            
var inputFiles = $("#idOfInput").get(0);
formData.append('file', inputFiles.files[0]);
```

Comment: Worked for me and I didn't have to change display from none or use a label tag.

Answer (score 2):

IE10 restrict submission of file field if the field is with 'display:node'.
If you remove the display:none the first fragment of code should work. 
However I'm not sure how to workaround this and why it works in second example.

Comment: This is happening in IE10, not 8. The input also needs to be hidden in some fashion or another in my case.